# Problems with title page: how to get rid of empty page and how to insert author name between title and subtitle?

Tags: margins, titles, author

My code:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{titling}

\graphicspath{ {/Users/corradobotta/Desktop/PhD/Thesis/Final/images} }

\newgeometry{
    top=1cm,
    bottom=1cm,
    outer=2.5cm,
    inner=2.5cm,
}

%\preauthor{\begin{flushright}\large \lineskip 0.5em}
%\postauthor{\par\end{flushright}}

\title{
    {\textbf{ \line(1,0){450}\\ \vspace{0.5cm} MY TITLE IS THERE AND IT IS LONG SO I FILL THIS SPACE WITH EMPTY WORDS\\ \line(1,0){250}}}\\ \vspace{1 cm}
    {\LARGE University of Looney Toones}\\ \vspace{1 cm}
    {\includegraphics[scale=0.1]{university.png}}\\ \vspace{1 cm}
    {\Large \textit{Department of Cartoons and Animations}}\\ \vspace{.5 cm}
    {\Large \textit{PhD Program in Cartoons Design and Colouring}}\\ \vspace{.5 cm}
    {\Large \textit{Number of the cycle}}\\ \vspace{1 cm}
    {\LARGE AUTHOR NAME (MY NAME)}\\ \vspace{1.5 cm}
    {\large \begin{flushleft} \textbf{Supervisor}: Prof. Daffy Duck \\ \vspace{0.25cm} \textbf{Coordinator}: Prof. Bugs Bunny \end{flushleft} }
}

\author{}
\date{}

\begin{document}
    
\begin{titlepage}
\addtolength{\topmargin}{-2cm}
\maketitle
\end{titlepage}

\chapter*{Abstract}
Abstract goes here

\chapter*{Dedication}
To mum and dad

\chapter*{Declaration}
I declare that..

\chapter*{Acknowledgements}
I want to thank...

\tableofcontents

\end{document}
```

I would like to get rid of the (second) empty page. The author name is in the \title command, is there any other way to get the same result but using \author? Does it makes any difference?

Comment: Generally I'd suggest not overloading `\maketitle` like this. Simply design the entire title page by hand inside the `titlepage` environment. Then you have complete control as to what goes where and in which sizes.

Comment: It seems you are writing a thesis/dissertation… why don't you start from one of the many (really many) existing templates that is close to your needs and change it as necessary?  *As author of the “novathesis” template, I suggest you take a look at it.* [https://github.com/joaomlourenco/novathesis].

Comment: @daleif with `titlepage` I should "manually" insert all the items?

Comment: @JoãoLourenço thank for your suggestion! I would like to write my own

Comment: You can write what ever you want inside the `titlepage` environment, there is no reason to use `\maketitle`, `\title` etc they just limit what you can do.